# Do I need to install "Swift" to make Charms work?

Tags: juju

I want to deploy charms. I tried [glance](http://jujucharms.com/~openstack-ubuntu-testing/quantal/glance) on jujucharms.com for example.

In section `REQUIRES>>` several different components are listed. If I don't need SWIFT do I have to install it?

Would this charm work without Swift?

Comment: Nopes its not required.

Answer (score 1):

No, you do not need to install Swift in order to make charms work.